# operator< redefinition on a std::pair<T1,T2> in class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I've got the following situation in a class template case:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
class targetClass{

public:

    typedef typename std::pair<T1, T2> ToSortType;
    typedef typename std::set<ToSortType> ContainerSort;  

    void bar(ToSortType a, ToSortType b);

private:

    ContainerSort container;
    bool operator<(const ToSortType& rhs) const;

}

template<class T1,class T2>
void targetClass<T1,T2>::bar(ToSortType a, ToSortType b){

    container.insert(a);
    container.insert(b);

}

template <class T1,class T2>
bool targetClass<T1,T2>::operator<(const ToSortType& rhs) const
{
    return this->first < rhs.first;
}
```

In main function something like this:

```
targetClass<int,T2> anObjectTarget;
T2 a;
T2 b;
anObjectTarget.bar(std::make_pair(0,a),std::make_pair(1,b));
```

Where `T2` is a user-defined type which generally does not have a defined `operator<`
In this particular case, `std::set` has to compare `std::pair<int,T2>` by firstly check an `operator<` (and others, maybe) for `int` type and then for `T2`. In this case, the compiler can not find a suitable operator for `T2`. In the previous snippet then I make a redefinition of the operator concerned but the compiler complains in this way:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:456: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const T2’ and ‘const T2’)
       || (!(__y.first < __x.first) && __x.second < __y.second); }
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've never redefined an operator before but looking to the documentation it looks correct to me (but not to the compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you overloaded is a member of `targetClass<T1,T2>` and takes two `ToSortType` as parameter. Thats not how an overload of the `<` operator works. Consider that for instances of class type the follwing two are equivalent:

```
 a < b
 a.operator<(b)
```

ie operators are just syntactic sugar for calling special member functions. The operator you wrote could only be called like

```
 targetClass<T1,T2> t;
 T1 a;
 T2 b;
 t.operator<(a,b);
```

but what the set tries to call is `a < b`, ie `a.operator(b)` and that apparently does not exist (`std::pair<T1,T2>` can only be comared via `<` when both `T1` and `T2` can).

Long story short: You cannot use your operator to compare two instances of `ToSortType`.

I would not recommend to try to overload the `operator<` for `std::pair<T1,T2>`, but rather use a custom type:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
class targetClass{

public:
    struct value_type {
        T1 first;
        T2 second;
        bool operator<(const value_type& other) {
             return first < rhs.first;
        }
    }
    using container_type = std::set<value_type>;    
    void bar(const value_type& a,const value_type& b);    
private:    
    container_type container;    
};
```

If you want to stay with `std::pair` then you can use the fact that `std::set` allows you to chose the type of the comparator. However, first I have to explain a bit not to confuse you because the following may appear to be contradicting the above (it does not). The default comparator that set uses is `std::less<Key>`, that is a type with an `operator()` that compares two element of type `Key`, it is something similar (but not exactly) like this:

```
template <typename Key>
struct less {
    bool operator() (const Key& a,const Key& b) const {
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

And this is the place where the compiler cannot find a `<` for your `Key` type (which is `std::pair<T1,T2>`). You can use your own comparator:

```
template <typename T1,typename T2>
struct my_comparator {
     bool operator() (const std::pair<T1,T2>& a, const std::pair<T1,T2>& b) const {
         return a.first < b.first;
     }
};
```

And then your set is

```
using container_type = std::set<typename std::pair<T1,T2>,typename my_comparator<T1,T2>>;
```

Comment: But what mistake did the compiler find?

Comment: @LucaJungla if either `T1` or `T2` have no `operator<` then there is no `std::pair<T1,T2>::operator<`. The operator you defined does not compare two `std::pair<T1,T2>`s

Comment: @LucaJungla the operator you defined is a member of `targetClass` and takes a `ToSortClass` as parameter, but thats just what I already wrote in the answer....You can compare a `T` to a `T` with an `operator<` that is a member of `T` and takes a parameter of type `T`

Comment: I see the point. But I still prefer a solution for overloading `std::pair` inside the class and not define a new struct for my purpose.

Comment: @LucaJungla why? `std::pair` is nothing but `struct pair { T1 first; T2 second; };` and in general you should not overload operators for types that are not yours

Comment: @LucaJungla `std::set`s second template parameter is the type of the comparator that is used to comapre two elements, that would be another option, I'll edit the answer....